# socket.io: socket reconnect in version 1.0

Tags: socket.io-1.0

I'm trying to migrate from Socket.IO 0.9 to 1.2.1, and I'm having some difficulty with socket reconnection.  In 0.9, I could do something like `socket.socket.reconnect();`, but unfortunately, `socket.socket` doesn't exist and `socket.io.reconnect` doesn't seem to reconnect my socket.  However, `socket.connect()` seems to reconnect using my original connect settings, but this doesn't seem right... why can't I use reconnect?  I've looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886481/socket-io-client-side-reconnect-not-working), but `forceNew` didn't seem to help.  Just for completion's sake, my connect code looks like this:

```
var socket = io.connect('/myNamespace', {forceNew: true, path: '/path/to/socket.io'});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `socket.connect()`... if anyone has a solution with `.reconnect()`, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround to this issue is to execute:

```
 socket.io.skipReconnect = false;
 socket.io.reconnect();
```